# Find the set of all integral values of $n$ for which

Tags: number-theory

Find the set of all integral values of $n$ for which $3^{2n} + 3n^2 + 7$ is a perfect square.
 
 I know a solution by inequality but was wondering what other solutions may be possible. 

My solution:-
 For a square $b^2$ then the nearest greater square is $(b + 1)^2$. Also, $(b+1)^2 = b^2 + 2b + 1.$
Therefore, for finding a square greater than $b^2$ we would have to add a number that is $≥ 2b + 1$.

Similarly, for finding a square greater than $3^{2n}$ we need to add a number $≥ (2  . 3^n) + 1 $
Hence,
$$3n^2 + 7 ≥ (2 . 3^n) + 1$$ 
$$3n^2 + 6 ≥ 2 . 3^n $$
$$n^2 + 2 ≥ 2 . 3^{n-1} $$
This is true only when $n = 1$ or $n = 2$. Now, it can be easily confirmed that no solution exists for $n = 1$ and a solution does for $n = 2$. Therefore, the only integral value of $n$ that meets the conditions is $n = 2.$

Comment: After "Also" I think you meant $\;(b+1)^2=b^2+2b+1\;$ .

Comment: Yeah, sorry. I'll correct it right away

Comment: Why to look for a complicated answer, when there is a very simple one? $3^{2n}+2n^2+7$ is always greater than the square of $3^n$, and "almost always" less than the square of $3^n+1$.

Comment: Yea but I was wondering if there was a better solution .

Comment: So, is there an easier way.

Comment: @Lucifer- Your solution is very elementary (which is *not* the same as easy) and very nice. +1