# $3^{2n}+3n^2+7$, a perfect square?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, square-numbers

> Find all positive integers $`n$' such that $$3^{2n}+3n^2+7$$ is a perfect square.

My attempt:

$9^n\equiv 1 \mod 4, 7 \equiv3 \mod 4$.

Also if $n$ is odd, $n^2\equiv1\mod 4 \implies 3n^2\equiv 3\mod 4$

Thus $9^n+3n^2+7\equiv7\mod4$ and therefore $9^n+3n^2+7\equiv3\mod4$

This means that $9^n+3n^2+7$ cannot be a perfect square when $n$ is odd.

If $n$ is even. Let $n=2k,k\in \mathbb{N}$

So we have $3^{2n}+3n^2+7=3^{4k}+12k^2+7$

We observe that if $k>1,$ then

$2k^2+1<3^{2k-1}$

$6(2k^2+1)<2\cdot 3^{2k}$

$12k^2+6<2\cdot 3^{2k}$

$12k^2+7<2\cdot 3^{2k}+1$

$3^{4k}+12k^2+7<3^{4k}+2\cdot 3^{2k}+1$

$3^{4k}<3^{4k}+12k^2+7<3^{4k}+2\cdot 3^{2k}+1$

$(3^{2k})^2<3^{4k}+12k^2+7<(3^{2k}+1)^2$

This implies that if $k>1,3^{4k}+12k^2+7$ cannot be a perfect square.

If $k=1,$ i.e., if $n=2,$ we have

$3^{2n}+3n^2+7=81+12+7=100$ which is a perfect square.

Hence $n=2$ is the only solution.

> Is there any other way to polish this argument? I had to work my way backwards in the $n$ is even case. Is there any better argument?

Comment: Hint : If $n$ is large enough , the number lies between $(3^n)^2$ and $(3^n+1)^2$ and can therefore not be a perfect square. Find out the smallest $n$ for which this is the case and test the rest.

Comment: See [art of problem solving](https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h2391094p19623981), and [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1965444/find-the-set-of-all-integral-values-of-n-for-which?noredirect=1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can't you instead observe that $3^{2n}$ is a perfect square for all nonnegative integers $n$, and that the next perfect square sfter $3^{2n}=(3^n)^2$ is $(3^n+1)^2=3^{2n}+(2\times3^n)+1$, which must be larger than $3^{2n}+3n^2+2$ for $n \ge 3$ [because $(2 \times 3^n)+1$ must be larger than $3n^2+2$ for all such $n$].